# International Student in United Kingdom eligible to Invest

Tags: united-kingdom, investing

I am a International Student studying in London with a Tier 4 Student VISA. Am I eligible to invest in stocks, bonds or funds through brokers or banks in the United Kingdom?

I tried to search Home Ministry documents for information, but I can't seem to find useful information.

Comment: try the HMRC the home office doesn't deal with taxation and so on

Comment: Tried HMRC as well, no relevant information provided.

Comment: Have you tried just opening on online dealing account with one of them and seeing if there is anything you can't comply with?  (Anyone using such services will probably be used to seeing "not for use by US persons" messages, for example).  There would probably be more conditions on opening an ISA (e.g being a UK taxpayer or at least having a national insurance number?) than a regular dealing account.  I note Hargreaves Lansdown's terms and conditions contain some text basically stating it's up to the user not to invest in anything they're not allowed to.